# Windows Won't Recognize Login Password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, login

I have a friend who has a laptop and it was working fine until two days ago. It won't accept his login password to get into Windows. I believe this may be a user profile corruption. When he was attempting to login it gave him an error, `Windows user profile is incorrect`. Somehow he got into his PC from Safe Mode. He then rolled back his PC. Now he cannot get into his PC at all again, telling him his password is incorrect.

I know he has checked his num-lock and caps lock. I do not believe it is a password error but a deeper error.

How can I help him fix his computer? What can I try to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Well, when you did rollback it must have changed his password to his old (and long forgotten) one.

Best option would be to download [Win7Live](http://reboot.pro/topic/7250-win7pe-with-winbuilder-74-76/) or [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/), and change the password to whatever you like.

Afterwards, if you suspect their might be some deeper problems, run a full scan with some Anti-Virus and then run a full ChkDsk.

Comment: He has only used one password on the system, and the rollback was to a few days before that problem.

Comment: Well, the solution still applies.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot again as safemode:

Open cmd(with privilegies)

type "net user %username% %password% /enable:yes"

type "net user %username% %password% /active:yes"

If this isn't working i would recomend to create a new Admin account and send all your important files to the new  recent new account.